# offset triangle on log-log pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Every post I've seen where they use pgfplot for plotting a log-log scale usually use a triangle to give the slope of the curve, something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=5,connect spies}]         
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        ymax=1,
        width = 7cm,
        legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east,draw=none},
    cycle list name=black white,
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.west)},xshift=-40pt,rotate=90}
        ]

\addplot table[row sep=crcr]{%
20 0.6676955877494976\\
54 0.4421832562458617\\
170 0.3070095744635237\\
594 0.21570767663834237\\
2210 0.15213719464595102\\
8514 0.1074559581550062\\
3341 0 0.07594309310973704\\
}
   coordinate [pos=0.85] (A)
   coordinate [pos=0.95]  (B)
   ;
\draw[] (A) -| (B);
node [pos=0.95,anchor=west]{$2.0$};
\node at (B) [anchor=north] {$?$};    

   \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to offset the triangle? I would like to indicate it as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the syntax provided by the `calc` library to calculate points shifted perpendicularly away from the line between `A` and `B`, and draw the triangle between those.

`clip mode=individual` was added so `0.272` wasn't clipped away.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=5,connect spies}]         
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        ymax=1,
        width = 7cm,
        legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east,draw=none},
    cycle list name=black white,
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.west)},xshift=-40pt,rotate=90},
        clip mode=individual
        ]

\addplot table[row sep=crcr]{%
20 0.6676955877494976\\
54 0.4421832562458617\\
170 0.3070095744635237\\
594 0.21570767663834237\\
2210 0.15213719464595102\\
8514 0.1074559581550062\\
3341 0 0.07594309310973704\\
}
   coordinate [pos=0.85] (A)
   coordinate [pos=0.95]  (B)
   ;

\coordinate (A') at ($(A)!3pt!90:(B)$);
\coordinate (B') at ($(B)!3pt!270:(A)$);
\draw  (A') -| (B') node[pos=0.25,above]{1} node[pos=0.75,right]{0.272};
\draw [shorten <=-3pt,shorten >=-3pt] (A') -- (B');
node [pos=0.95,anchor=west]{$2.0$};
\node at (B) [anchor=north] {$?$};    

   \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```